# Delete all elements in array apart from certain ones

Tags: c#, arrays, list

So I have an array (string[]) and I have an array with the number of lines I wish to keep, is there a specific way to have it remove all but these, or maybe copy these into an empty array ?

This is the array with the line numbers

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dumpFile.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dumpFile[i].StartsWith(@"     ""videoId"":"))
                {
                    arrayIndex.Add(i);
                    string stringI = i.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("lines.txt", stringI);                       
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean you have an array that contains for example, 1,3,4,6 meaning you would want the strings at indexes 2 and 5 removed?

Comment: You can use the `Select` and `Where` methods to achieve what you want, or go non-LINQ and populate a new Array yourself. Anything more I can't really say unless you show some code and a better description of how you determine which lines you want to keep.

Comment: @Stuart yes, that's the format of the array which I have, but the numbered lines are the ones which I wish to keep

Comment: @Abion47 added some code ,hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Linq:**

To keep only certain elements in an array you can use the below code. Feel free to specify your condition in place of `line.StartsWith()`. You can also save these to a file like you were doing using a single statement instead of a loop.

```
string[] selected = dumpFile.Where(line => line.StartsWith(@"     ""videoId"":")).ToArray();

// Now saving these lines to a file in a single line instead of using a loop
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("lines.txt", selected);
```